# How to download a phrasebook from google translate

Tags: file-system, google-translate

So i've been using google translate for a while and there are a bunch of translated words and phrases that i have asked for to date stored on the device. I now want to take a copy of them to my PC (in any tractable text format) so that i can use a decent text editor / script to convert them to anki format (a flashcard app) so that i can memorize them.

Does anyone know how to get at this data? I had a quick look through the file system on my android phone (which incidentally, is a samsung galaxy S III) and i couldn't see anything obvious there. I reason that the phrases i have used must be in there somewhere because they are displayed on the phone even when there is no internet access from the device.

Comment: I'd actually be glad if there was an automatic tool to achieve this... or an easy way to sync my phrasebook to Anki when I add more phrases to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are logged into your Google account, your Phrasebook will [synchronize across devices](http://googletranslate.blogspot.co.il/2013/05/take-your-phrasebook-on-goand-translate.html) and you can also access it from the web interface of Google Translate. Furthermore, after importing to Anki you can [synchronize your decks](http://ankisrs.net/docs/am-manual.html#cloud-sync) across devices.

1. In the web interface of [Google Translate](http://translate.google.com/), show the Phrasebook by clicking the Phrasebook icon in the upper right corner:
   [image: Show Phrasebook]

   2. Export the Phrasebook to a Google spreadsheet by clicking the Export icon, again in the upper right corner:
      [image: Export to Google Sheets]
   3. Click "Yes, import the data".
   4. Export the resulting spreadsheet to .csv format:
      [image]
   5. The .csv file has four fields: source language, target language, source phrase, and target phrase. To import the data into the [Anki desktop application](http://ankisrs.net/#download), choose File -> Import in the menu, and in the dialog that opens, choose **Front** for field 3 and **Back** for field 4:
      [image]
   6. Click Import, and you're done :)

Comment: Great tip with the Export Phrasebook to Google Sheets. However one thing I notice is that my entire Phrasebook is not exported. I looked into it further and found that all phrases that I have saved using the Google translate app on my phone were not synced with the phrases I saved from the web version of Google translate. Is there any way to sync the web and phone app versions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a tool to import from Google Translate:
https://github.com/jamhed/anki

Comment: Welcome to  Android Enthusiasts! Link-only answers are frowned upon all over SE. Please [edit] your post and add a few more details, including the name of the tool (or if the link dies, your post will be pretty useless – which would be a pity, as this "Anki" tool seems to be well tailored for the OP's issue). For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).